# Intellij addling user home path before $FilePath$ while setting external tool on window 10

Tags: java, intellij-idea, external-tools

I am trying to set external tool in intellij 2020. To add external tool, I went
File-> Setting-> Tools-> External Tools Than I add a external tool. In argument box I added one command and $FilePath$. But every time I execute that external tool, Intellij prepend /home/user before file path. this is happening only for files. For directories it is working fine. This issues is on windows

Answer (score 1):

`$FilePath$` is the full path to the file. If you need a relative path use `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$` or `$FilePathRelativeToSourcepath$`.

[image: file path]